# Points to be looked into while upgrading from redis-2.8.19 to redis-3.0.2

Tags: redis, version, upgrade, compatibility

What are the points to know and access before upgrading from **Redis-2.8.19** to **Redis-3.0.2**? 
Do any compatibility issues exist between a **master with older version** and **slave with the newer version** or vice versa?